# react native recyclerlistview if state changed its scroll to top

Tags: react-native, expo

If I change any state or change the textinput value, if it changed then its scroll to top and leave the textinput. Or If I like one product, its autoamticlly scroll to top if the array is changed. Anyone can help me ?

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect, forwardRef, memo } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { RecyclerListView, LayoutProvider, DataProvider } from 'recyclerlistview';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { addAmountOnCartItem } from '../../../redux/slice/product/shopping_cart';
import faker from 'faker';
import ButtonWithoutLoader from '../../ButtonWithoutLoader';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Shopping_cart_list = ({ datas, onPressSetting }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const provider = useMemo(() => {
    return new DataProvider(
      (r1, r2) => {
        return r1 !== r2;
      },
      index => {
        return 'id:' + index;
      }
    )
  }, []);

  const dataProvider = useMemo(() => {
    return provider.cloneWithRows(datas);
  }, [datas, provider]);

  const [update, updateRecycler] = useState({
    update: false
  });

  const handleChange = (e, product_id) => {
    dispatch(addAmountOnCartItem({ value: e, product_id }));
    updateRecycler(prevState => {
      return {
        update: !prevState
      }
    });
  };

  const layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider((i) => {
    return dataProvider.getDataForIndex(i).type;
  }, (type, dim) => {
    switch(type) {
      case 'NORMAL':
        dim.height = 250;
        dim.width = width * 0.9;
      break;
      default:
        dim.height = 0;
        dim.width = 0;
      break;
    }
  });

  const RenderData = memo(({ product_id, product_name, price, product_image, amount, username }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{height: 250, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginBottom: 16}}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.profile_info}>
            <Image source={{uri: faker.image.avatar()}} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.profile_image} />
            <Text style={styles.username}>{ username }</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressSetting(product_id)}>
            <AntDesign name="setting" size={24} color="#444" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Image source={{uri: product_image}} style={styles.image} />
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{product_name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Preis: {price}</Text>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Anzahl: </Text>
              <AntDesign name="minussquareo" style={{marginRight: 6}} size={24} color="black" />
              <TextInput onBlur={() => handleChange(1, product_id)} value={ isNaN(amount) ? '' : amount.toString() } onChangeText={e => handleChange(e, product_id)} style={{height: 28, width: 28, borderRadius: 4, textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: '#eee'}} />
              <AntDesign name="plussquareo" style={{marginLeft: 6}} size={24} color="black" />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.header, { marginTop: 4 }]}>
          <ButtonWithoutLoader onPress={() => updateRecycler(prevState => !prevState)} title="Jetzt Kaufen!" width={width * 0.9} />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  });

  const rowRenderer = (type, data) => {
    const { product_id, product_name, price, product_image, amount, username } = data.item;
    return <RenderData product_id={product_id} product_name={product_name} price={price} product_image={product_image} amount={amount} username={username} />
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingBottom: 85}}>
      <RecyclerListView
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
        forceNonDeterministicRendering={true}
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        style={{marginLeft: width * 0.05, marginRight: width * 0.05}}
        extendedState={update}
        scrollViewProps={{showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false}}
      />
    </View>
  )
};
```

Flatlist:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, memo, useMemo } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Animated, FlatList, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { addAmountOnCartItem } from '../../../redux/slice/product/shopping_cart';
import faker from 'faker';
import ButtonWithoutLoader from '../../ButtonWithoutLoader';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Shopping_cart = ({ datas, onPressSetting }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [update, updateRecycler] = useState({
    update: false
  });

  const handleChange = (e, product_id) => {
    dispatch(addAmountOnCartItem({ value: e, product_id }));
    updateRecycler(prevState => {
      return {
        update: !prevState
      }
    });
  };

  const RenderItem = memo(({ item }) => {
    const { product_id, product_name, price, product_image, amount, username, size, colors, desc, selectedColor, selectedSize } = item.item;
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{height: 300, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginBottom: 16}}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.profile_info}>
            <Image source={{uri: faker.image.avatar()}} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.profile_image} />
            <Text style={styles.username}>{ username }</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressSetting(product_id)}>
            <AntDesign name="setting" size={24} color="#444" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProductStack', {
                product_id,
                desc,
                price,
                product_image,
                username,
                user_profil_image: faker.image.avatar(),
                size,
                colors,
              })} style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Image source={{uri: product_image}} style={styles.image} />
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{product_name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Preis: {price}</Text>

            <Text style={styles.text}>Farbe: {selectedColor}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Größe: {selectedSize}</Text>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Anzahl: </Text>
                <AntDesign name="minussquareo" style={{marginRight: 6}} size={24} color="black" />
                <TextInput onBlur={() => handleChange(1, product_id)} value={ isNaN(amount) ? '' : amount.toString() } onChangeText={e => handleChange(e, product_id)} style={{height: 28, width: 28, borderRadius: 4, textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: '#eee'}} />
                <AntDesign name="plussquareo" style={{marginLeft: 6}} size={24} color="black" />
            </View> 
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={[styles.header, { marginTop: 4 }]}>
          <ButtonWithoutLoader onPress={() => updateRecycler(prevState => !prevState)} title="Jetzt Kaufen!" width={width * 0.9} />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  });
  return (
    <FlatList 
      data={datas}
      keyExtractor={item => item.item.product_id + Math.random(100)}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <RenderItem item={item}/>}
      contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
      removeClippedSubviews={true}
      initialNumToRender={2}
      maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
      extraData={update}
      updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
    />
  );
};
```

........................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

If you see the docs of [RecyclerView](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview#props), you will see for **extendedState** prop:

> In some cases the data passed at row level may not contain all the info that the item depends upon, you can keep all other info outside and pass it down via this prop. Changing this object will cause everything to re-render. Make sure you don't change it often to ensure performance. Re-renders are heavy.

Based on your code you are updating this prop in button click and text change handler, this will eventually re-render your screen as per the description. So, here you would need to revise your logic to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I removed the extendedState for a test and it renders again. So its not extendedState fault.

Answer (score 0):

I recently just solved this problem in my own project so I'd be glad to help.

The main issue is that you can't have ANY UI related state in your list items. None. You must instead move all of that information to be transferred through props.

I see your only instance of that is through your TextInput.  This could be difficult. So my first question would then be: do you really need RecyclerListView? Unless your list is thousands of items long, and items have a complicated/image intensive UI, I'd suggest FlatList for this project.

If you do continue to need RecyclerListView, I'd suggest making it so after a textinput is finished ('finished' as in maybe after a 3 second timer or, when they press 'submit' or something like that), you change the dataProvider's data object. Change the item at the index you need, and then resubmit it with cloneWithRows()

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I think I use flatlist instead of this its only for a shopping cart. I dont think that a user have 1000 cart items :D. But I use recyclerlistview because of the performance. In the shopping cart Screen I have also a modal, So if I use this with flatlist and open it, then its slow. This was the reason to choose recyclerlistview. But one question. How I change the item at the index in recyclerlistview do you have any link or tut for this ?

Comment: Yea, for a shopping cart I would highly suggest FlatList. It's a lot easier to implement too. The only time I've had to use RecyclerListView for its high performance was in an infinite social media feed with lots of images and videos in each post.

I'm surprised you're reporting something slow with the modal. Feel free to show your code with that and we can see what's going on there. A simple modal shouldn't be decreasing performance.

Comment: As per your question about changing the item at the index, I'm referring to changing the actual 'datas' object. Your store of data that you put into 'provider.cloneWithRows(datas)'. Change the object at the index you want there, and then reset it with provider.cloneWithRows(datas) again. This will update the UI without even requiring a refresh, since it'll all be passed through props.

Comment: I will test it again with flatlist and modal, if the problem comes with slowness I will post the code thanks for your both answers i am very thankful about this

Comment: hello my friend I have used it with flatlist, but if I type anything in the input field it goes automactilly onfocused. Why ? I edit the flatlist code above

Comment: Now that I've had a moment to look more, I can say there's a few things wrong with the TextInput component itself. And since we're using FlatList now, you can do it the standard way you would use a TextInput component anywhere. In RenderItem, add state there. Something like this:

const [text, updateText] = React.useState(amount)

And the TextInput can use the standard too:

value={amount.toString} onChangeText={e => updateText(e)}

Your current handleChange function has far too much stuff going on that shouldn't be included in a TextInput's onChangeText, and should be moved elsewhere.

Comment: In addition, since you said you were having performance problems, you shouldn't be using anonymous functions for anything in lists. It get's really heavy. Especially RenderItem. Change that to a normal function.

renderItem={RenderItem}

Comment: Oh I see what you were doing with HandleChange now. You were trying to update text through there. Yea, that's not gonna work lol. Dispatch and the store are async and not designed to work with onChangeText. No worries. As I mentioned earlier, since you're not using RecyclerListView anymore, you don't need to pass that information through props anymore. And should be doing it through local state in RenderItem as shown in my above comment.

Comment: If I write renderItem={RenderItem} then I get RenderItem is not a function because I use memo